# How to detect that variable stop changing in while loop

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
while True:    
    tensionline = image_tracker(tension_line, lower_red, upper_red)
    ropecounter = image_tracker(rope_counter, lower_white, upper_white)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(ropecounter[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    rope_meters = pytesseract.image_to_string(rgb, lang='en', config='--psm 7')
    d = threading.Thread(target=track_variable_changes, args=(rope_meters,))
    d.start()
   

    cv2.imshow('tension line', tensionline[0])
    cv2.imshow('rope counter', ropecounter[1])
```

rope_meters - it's a variable that constantly change, Im trying to detect a point, when this var hasn't changed for 5 sec but I need to do it without breaking the loop.

```
def track_variable_changes(my_var):
    last_change_time = time.monotonic()
    last_var = 0
    while True:
        if my_var != last_var:
            last_var = my_var
            last_change_time = time.monotonic()
        
        if time.monotonic() - last_change_time > 5:
            print("Variable has not changed in 5 seconds.")
            last_change_time = time.monotonic()
```

track_variable_changes doesnt work... it doesn't detect changing and stoping loop in spite of using threading....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is spawning countless threads in the infinite loop, which, other issues aside, is probably undesired. A better design would be to maintain a timestamp of the last change in the same `while True` loop, something like:

```py
last_rope_meters = None
last_change_time = time.monotonic()

while True:    
    ...    

    rope_meters = ...

    if rope_meters != last_rope_meters:
        last_rope_meters = rope_meters
        last_change_time = time.monotonic()
 
    if time.monotonic() - last_change_time > 5::
        # readings haven't changed in 5 seconds, do something
    
    ...
```